# How to position div based on text selection position

Tags: jquery

Let's say I select some text. I want a `<div>` to appear at the beginning of the selected text.

So far I have the code to track the selected text:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#actual_verse").mouseup(function() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    
    if (/\S/.test(text)) {
      alert(text);
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='actual_verse'> A justo sit aut sit sed. Wisi a cras sed. Feugiat mus nulla sagittis proin, feugiat accumsan turpis neque, velit nec odio bibendum, cum dui mi turpis interdum, aptent risus vestibulum eu vitae sed. Nulla facilisis, id quis cubilia vel suscipit, fermentum ante aliquam nunc. Scelerisque lacinia, ut molestie dui libero arcu elit nec, faucibus tenetur maecenas sit ipsum rutrum. Non amet erat non sit quis, nonummy magna elit integer in sed in, suspendisse quis velit blandit, interdum quam dui mollis vestibulum elementum, urna donec eros eget. Mauris aliquam montes a, sem est sed, eveniet lacus nibh, donec ornare sit, aptent sit rutrum gravida. Wisi et amet lobortis. </span>
```

**How do I now make a `<div>` appear at the start of the selected text?**

Comment: Do you want to wrap the selected text, or do you want to add a `div` as a hint box to beginning of selected text?

Comment: You can't nest a `div` inside a `span`, is invalid html.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way possible :

https://jsfiddle.net/1mjhsypk/

Add `text = '<div>'+text+'</div>';` before alert.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position a div where the selection start you can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.conttext').mouseup(function() {
    var highlight = window.getSelection();
    var spn = '<span class="highlight">' + highlight + '<div class="mydiv"></div></span>';
    var text = $('.conttext').text();
    $('.conttext').html(text.replace(highlight, spn));
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  position: relative;
}
.mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: gold;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conttext">How hard can it be to achieve this here and now. Will it be difficult or can it be done with great simplicity</div>
```

Comment: On `mousedown` you would have to remove the highlight span, otherwise you have bugs (try selecting inside already selected text several times).

Comment: @skobaljic You're right. This is just the basic idea

Comment: Awesome job, is there any way to keep the highlighted text? This div will have colors to style the text.